# How do I return concatenated array values to a label?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that compares two arrays, then counts the number of matches and mismatches. If there are mismatches, it stores the items into an array and would tell me which items don't match.

My Mismatched array returns the correct values to a listbox, but I need to return it to a label, with concatenated values.

So far only thing I've tried that doesn't error out is `label.text = string.join(", " mismatched)` but it doesn't return actual values.

```cs
//correct counter
int correct = 0;

//incorrect counter
int incorrect = 0;

ArrayList Mismatch = new ArrayList();

if (A[0] == B[0]) {
    correct++;
} else {
    incorrect++;
    Mismatch.Add("1");
}

if (A[1] == B[1]) {
    correct++;
} else {
    incorrect++;
    Mismatch.Add("2");
}
```

When I try to return concat values in a label, it returns 'system.collection...'.

It should return:

If A[0] = B[0] and A[1] = B[1] match, then the label = null or blank (doesn't matter which).

If A[0] = B[0] but A[1] != B[1] then the label = "2".

If neither match, then the label returns "1, 2"

Comment: Reguarding the use of ArrayList please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks  Don't use it in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an ArrayList, use a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).  You can also use a `for` loop to iterate over the arrays:

```
int correct = 0;
int incorrect = 0;     
if (A.Length == B.Length)
{
    List<string> Mismatch = new List<string>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= A.Length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i-1] == B[i-1])
        {
            correct++;
        }
        else
        {
            incorrect++;
            Mismatch.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    label1.Text = String.Join(", ", Mismatch);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I updated what I already had and got the desired effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment reguarding ArrayList. I used 2 arrays and 2 List

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] A = { "Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John" };
        string[] B = { "Peter", "Mark", "Paul", "John" };

        List<string> Mismatch = new List<string>();
        List<string> Matched=new List<string>();
        if (A.Length != B.Length) { return; }
        int i;
        for (i =0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] == B[i])
            { Matched.Add($"A and B match with {A[i]} at position {i}"); }
            else
            { Mismatch.Add($"Mismatch at position {i} A contains {A[i]} B contains {B[i]}"); }
        }
        int correct = Matched.Count;
        int incorrect = Mismatch.Count;
        MessageBox.Show($"The number of correct is {correct}{Environment.NewLine}The number of incorrect is {incorrect}");
        label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Mismatch);
        label4.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Matched);
    }
```